# Tree (Hierarchical) Structure in Hibernate and GAE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

I want to model a hierarchical data in Hibernate (and also in GAE).

The entity structure is similar to as below:

```
class Node<T>
{
    Long id;
    T nodeValue;
    Node<T> parent;
    List<Node<T>> children;
}
```

I am fine with using JPA annotations, if that's necessary (which I think will be).

The following features should be supportable:

- <strike>Adding a new root (there can be multiple trees in the database - with `parent = null`)</strike>. Can do without this, if this can result in a non-starter to design (by using some "invisible great-grandfather root node")
- Adding a new node to any parent
- Deleting a node and it's entire sub-tree structure
- Updating a node (say, changing parent/children etc)
- Ability to travel top-down as well as bottom-up within a tree
- And most importantly... Given an `id`, ability to fetch the specific node and then travel upwards (ancestor-path) / downwards (children-path)

---

## More Info (Updates)

Here's what I logically want to achieve:

- Have a flat list of categories in a table. These categories have no relation with each other
- Have a table that will create multiple "set of hierarchies" for these categories.

Why do I need them?

I am creating an application wherein documents can be submitted to these categories.

However, each user may have a different view point to the same categories. For example, I may want to create a hierachy `Company -> Departments -> HR -> World -> Asia -> India` whereas somebody else may want to see `Company -> World -> Asia -> India -> Departments -> HR`.

Any help to model this structure will be great.

Comment: Please help me model the entity (add few items if required) and create appropriate configuration (annotation, hbm.xml file etc whatever required). :)

Answer (score -1):

What you want is probably something like this (from Hibernate's test suite):

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/annotations/manytoone/Node.java

But without any specific question, it's hard to answer...

Comment: I am putting up some more specifics in the main question itself... let me know if those insights can help you to help me :)

Comment: @partenon: The github link is broken.

Comment: Although I agree that it's disappointing to face a broken link, it shouldn't be that hard to look up this on the Hibernate test suite (I mentioned the source in the answer itself). Besides, it's a good practice to look at the test suite, to find great usage examples. In any case, I've fixed the link.